# C# autorun issue

Tags: c#, registry

I set my C# application to auto-run on start up though the registry.
The issue is that when that:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory //returns C:\Windows\System32
```

Instead of the file's actual location.
Why is it causing this and is there an alternative?

Im using 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CurrentDirectory` is not the location of your program; it's the folder that the program was started in.  (although it can change later)

You're looking for `Path.GetDirectory(typeof(YourType).Assembly.Location)`

Comment: No it is not the folder the app has started in, tested it in practice and found it to be variable, ex: if you open a file in `c:\\folder` through an `OpenFileDialog`, the new working directory will be `c:\\folder`. Haven't tested your answer but the `CurrentDirectory` is most definitely not reliable

Comment: +1 or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx

Comment: @SSK: Yes, it is.  FileDialogs will change the current directory unless configured not to.

Comment: The point was that the `CurrentDirectory` is not constant and will not necessarily show to the place that app was started in.

Comment: @SSK: I never said it was constant.  I'll clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what the problem is, but you can always change the CurrentDirectory for your application as follows:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath`

Answer (score 0):

When I create the autorun at the startup of windows in C#, I use the next instruction to get my executable path:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath.ToString();
```